# Heroku: command not found. Working on Virtualenv

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv

I see similar questions, but those are `Ruby on Rails` questions. I'm working on a `virtualenv` using `python` and `django`.

I installed `django-toolbelt`, I also tried `pip install heroku`. When I do:

```
whereis heroku
```

I get this:

```
heroku: /usr/bin/heroku
```

But when I try `heroku create` I get:

```
heroku: command not found
```

??
Thanks a lot for your help. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | bash

echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now I upgraded my heroku cli from 7.7 to 7.25 via apt-get. I am on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

```
    (hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ sudo snap install --classic heroku
    heroku v7.25.0 from Heroku✓ installed
```

However, if I run a heroku command from inside pipenv, I get

```
    (hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ heroku --version
    bash: /usr/bin/heroku: No such file or directory
```

But from outside pipenv, it performs as expected:

```
    malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ heroku --version
    heroku/7.25.0 linux-x64 node-v11.14.0
```

Note, there really is no /usr/bin/heroku. There is a /usr/local/heroku, but the only thing inside there is a folder called "vendor", with other things inside vendor. There is no /usr/local/heroku/bin as suggested in the op's answer to his own question. However, since this is a 'snap' install, I looked there and found:

```
    /snap/heroku/current/bin
```

So modifying the op's solution, I did:

```
    echo 'PATH="/snap/heroku/curent/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

Restart, and:

```
    (hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ heroku --version
    heroku/7.25.0 linux-x64 node-v11.14.0
```

Problem solved! Even better...

```
    malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ heroku --version
    heroku/7.25.0 linux-x64 node-v11.14.0
```

it still works outside pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but all I had to do was close  the terminal and restarted it.